# Recurring Alarms in Windows Phone 8

Tags: 8.0, functionality, alarms

I recently moved from a Blackberry to Windows Phone 8.  I would like to set up a couple of recurring alarms.  One for every other Monday and another for the last day of the month.  It was easy to do on my Blackberry, but I can't figure it out with Windows Phone.  Is this possible with the stock alarms app?

Comment: I don't think *Every other Monday* or *last day of the month* is supported by the scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

If 'Every other Monday' means every Monday from now on, you can do that with the alarm app.

Last day of the month is something that is possible with the calendar app. I created an appointment (in my case I used the web interface of calendar.live.com) and added an reminder for the last day in a month. The appointment has successfully shown up in the phone. Note: unfortunately, the custom entry in the list for creating that series has no functionality. You can do this only using another app or account that syncs those appointments to the phone.

Comment: I know this has a feeling of a work-around, but somehow this is also kind of a complex criteria. Note: by work around I mean I need to use the live calendar to create/edit the series, not that I need an appointment. The recurrence is (IMHO) too complex to really name this an alarm. Alarm is more like 'please wake me up, so I don't get too late to work'.

Comment: hmm I read every other Monday as Every Two Weeks. What you described sounded more like Every Monday. Maybe the OP will chime in

Answer (score -1):

Last day of the month is tricky because of the different number of days per month but could be approached as follows;
1) Create a calendar entry for the first day of the month
2) set **Occurs** to 'day 1 of every month'
3) set the **Reminder** to be '1 day'.

That will alert you on the last day of the previous month and will not worry about how many days in the month there are!

It's a kludge, but it does the job!  Good Luck!!

Comment: He is looking for a recurring alarm, not a reminder for a calendar event?